# What is the difference between normal and hard?

Tags: poker-night-at-the-inventory

As far as I can see the rewards are the same? does the AI play differently, are the cards rigged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the increased difficulty, the NPCs change their playstyles slightly and act less random. It makes it a *little* easier to try to strategize and makes the game feel a bit more like a "real" poker game, but it's still difficult to properly bluff, for example. Reviews say that the poker experience for the player is more consistent with the higher difficulty setting.

[Read](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/11/29/poker-night-at-the-inventory-review/) [some](http://news.bigdownload.com/2010/11/24/review-poker-night-at-the-inventory/) [reviews](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2010/11/24/wot-i-think-poker-night-at-the-inventory/).

Basically, if you are an experienced poker and Texas Hold'Em player, you won't find the game very challenging (and may indeed find it more frustrating if you try to apply normal poker strategy to the game), so setting the difficulty higher will probably be more rewarding for you.

Comment: Well yes my initial perception was that Hard was ever so slightly harder, but randomness is not something people are very good at dealing with intuitively so it isn't at all obvious that a review based on probably limited number of hands played with no statistical analysis is correct. still this is probably correct